# Rank of a coherent sheaf using resolution by vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

The rank of a coherent sheaf is defined in terms of the Hilbert polynomial (See Huybrechts-Lehn 1.2.2 or [Rank of a coherent sheaf in terms of coefficients of the Hilbert polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127935/rank-of-a-coherent-sheaf-in-terms-of-coefficients-of-the-hilbert-polynomial)).

Now let $\mathcal{F}\to X$ be a coherent sheaf over a projective manifold, so that there exists a resolution $E^{\bullet}\to\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ by vector bundles.

Is there a way to define (or recover for instance) the rank of $\mathcal{F}$ using the resolution $E^{\bullet}$ (just like we can define the first Chern class for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Hilbert polynomials are additive over exact sequences: if $0\to F_n\to \cdots \to F_0\to 0$ is an exact sequence, then $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^iH_{F_i}(\lambda) =0$.

Comment: Does that mean that $rk(\mathcal{F})=\sum_i(-1)^irk(E^i)=\chi(E^{\bullet})$?

Comment: @BinAcker Yes (this also follows really easily by the definition as rank at generic point, using generic freeness)